# Exchange column order of table after it is created

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table with 4 columns. I need to change the structure of the table. I need to interchange the position of the 4th and 2nd columns permanently. Is this possible in Oracle?

Comment: What's the need to reorder the columns?  You can select them in any order in your statements, and you can insert them in any order as well.

Comment: I agree with all the comments and answers asking "why" as there is no logical reason to change the column order. However, in 12c there is a trick to do it: http://tkyte.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/12c-silly-little-trick-with-invisibility.html

Answer (score 5):

Not possible. See [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ#How_does_one_add_a_column_to_the_middle_of_a_table.3F).

> Oracle only allows columns to be added to the end of an existing
>   table.

So you must drop and recreate the tables.

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview. And it is possible according to the interviewer.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TBL as SELECT * FROM TBL_ORIG;
ALTER TABLE TBL_ORIG ADD COLUMN COL3;
DROP TABLE TBL_ORIG;
CREATE TABLE TBL_ORIG AS SELECT COL1, COL3, COL2 FROM TMP_TBL;
DROP TABLE TMP_TBL
```

You would need to consider indexes as well as storage concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Why in the world is this necessary?  Column order means nothing in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

*Swap of columns col1 and col2*
It is assumed that col1 is `int` and col2 is `varchar2(20)`

```
-- drop all indexes and constraints concerning col1 and col2
alter table your_table add temp_col int;          -- type of col1
update your_table set col1 = null, temp_col = col1;
alter table your_table modify col1 varchar2(20);  -- type of col2
update your_table set col2 = null, col1 = col2;
alter table your_table modify col2 int;           -- type of col1
update your_table set col2 = temp_col;
alter table your_table drop column temp_col;
alter table your_table rename column col1 to temp_col;
alter table your_table rename column col2 to col1;
alter table your_table rename column temp_col to col1;  
-- recreate indexes and constraints
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply rename table columns if they are the same datatype. If not then Alter - see Sean and Egor examples.

Rename:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables006.htm#ADMIN11662

And on the interview they are looking for Sean's answer. Just FYI...